# Restricting NFS share access to particular IPs or hosts and restricting others on suse

Tags: linux, nfs, suse, nfsv4

I have created a shared folder **/data01/share** on one Suse Gnu/Linux and also made entry for host(client) machine in **/etc/exports** **/data01/share  10.241.200.53(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)** . But i am getting this after **exportfs -a**

```
exportfs: No options for /data01/share  10.241.200.53(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check) : suggest (sync) to avoid warning
exportfs: /etc/exports [2]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 'no_subtree_check' specified for export ":/data01/share  10.241.200.53(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)".
Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x

exportfs: Failed to stat /data01/share  10.241.200.53(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check): No such file or directory
```

**cat /etc/os-release**

```
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12-SP3"
VERSION_ID="12.3"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp3"
```

**systemctl status nfs-server.service**

```
nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service.d
           └─nfsserver.conf
        /run/systemd/generator/nfs-server.service.d
           └─order-with-mounts.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-07-24 02:32:03 EDT; 2h 34min ago
 Main PID: 2562 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 512)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service

Jul 24 02:32:03 OPT001CORE0002 systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Jul 24 02:32:03 OPT001CORE0002 systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

**cat /etc/exports**

```
# See the exports(5) manpage for a description of the syntax of this file.
# This file contains a list of all directories that are to be exported to
# other computers via NFS (Network File System).
# This file used by rpc.nfsd and rpc.mountd. See their manpages for details
# on how make changes in this file effective.

/data01/share  10.241.200.53(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

**ls -la /data01/share**

```
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 4 acmuser acmgrp 36 Jul 24 04:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 acmuser acmgrp 65 Jul 24 04:16 ..
drwxrwxrwx 3 acmuser acmgrp 18 Jul 24 04:18 support
drwxrwxrwx 5 acmuser acmgrp 45 Jul 24 04:17 upgrade
```

Comment: Can you paste `cat /etc/os-release` and `systemctl status nfs-server.service`?

Comment: Not sure if I get what you have tried so far, can you also paste `cat /etc/exports`? Can the client reach the nfs server and vice versa? Is your firewall active?

Comment: Alright, then please add the output of `ls -la /data01/share` to the question. You can remove sensitive data, if necessary.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `no_subtree_check`? I read that in a similar question.

Comment: no it doesnt work

Comment: Did you change your settings and only tried to run `exportfs -a`? Try restarting `nfs-server service` and run `exportfs -av` again. Or run `exportfs -avr` to re-export all shares.

Comment: still getting same results

Comment: I can only reproduce this when I rename my export directory but don't change the /etc/exports file accordingly, if I run exportfs I also get `exportfs: Failed to stat /test-nfs-a: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the option subtree_check to /etc/exports like this:

```
# cat /etc/exports
/views_raw      10.143.3.44(rw,sync,no_root_squash,subtree_check)
```

Restart NFS service

```
# systemctl restart nfs-server
# exportfs -av
```